# Temporarily disabling VBA's worksheet_change()

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that I need to run to initialise my monthly data dump of raw data. This works fine.

In addition, I have a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change()` step that runs each time a cell's value is changed. This works fine.

My issue is that as my initialisation macro makes many changes, it keeps firing off the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change()`. Is there a way I can have it disabled until after the initialisation has finished running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must temporarily disabile eventi with

`Application.EnableEvents = False`

And then set it back to `True` by initializing macro end

To ensure you actually set it back you'd better do this settings inside your initializing macro itself and use an error handler, like follows:

```
Sub InitializingMacro ()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Your code here...

ErrHandler:
   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
application.enableevents = false
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12835362)

Comment: @gofr1. thank you for the note :) yes this is a very bad answer :D

Comment: the answer needs no more explanation in my opinion, in fact it's the only answer possible. The question itself prooves no google search before hand. The OP is not even providing code or what steps he might have done...

Answer (score 0):

I add a global value `bAlreadyinChange` and set it to `True`, then at the start of the `Worksheet_Change` event, check that value and exit the sub if it's already set, so...

```
Sub Worksheet_Change()
    if bAlreadyinChange Then Exit Sub
    bAlreadyinChange = True ' set this so any updates don't fire the event again
    ' do whatever here
    bAlreadyinChange = False
End Sub
```

This means I can use the change event to apply whatever updates or adjustments I like to the sheet without firing the event recursively. Although I can't see any reason why you couldn't do the same thing using the `Application.EnableEvents` in Rosetta's post

Comment: this kind of method is for userforms, in worksheets you can use `application.enableevents=false`